# ¿Qué es la doble negación (!!) en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, booleano

En algunos códigos he visto una doble negación `!!` delante de una variable, por ejemplo:

```
{ token: !!localStorage.getItem('token') }
```

Entiendo que se usa una negación `!` para realizar una negación lógica en una expresión.

Pero una doble negación lo convierte otra vez al estado como lo ha recibido al principio, por ejemplo:

```js
var token = true;

console.log( token ); // true
console.log( !token ); // false
console.log( !!token ); // true
```

¿Para qué y porqué se usa esta técnica en JavaScript?

Comment: Hay una explication mucho mas simple.. el `!!` es un casteo a booleano.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> El primero `!` convertirá un valor que no sea ni verdadero (true) ni
>   falso (false) en un valor que sea verdadero (true) o falso (false), y
>   luego lo invertirá.

Seguro que ahora estarás más confuso, pero veamos unos ejemplos:

```js
var token_null = null;
console.log( 'token_null   =', token_null );   // null
console.log( '!token_null  =', !token_null );   // true
console.log( '!!token_null =', !!token_null );  // false

console.log( '-----------' );

var token_undefined = undefined;
console.log( 'token_undefined   =', token_undefined );   // undefined
console.log( '!token_undefined  =', !token_undefined );  // true
console.log( '!!token_undefined =', !!token_undefined ); // false

console.log( '-----------' );

var token_string = 'mi_token';
console.log( 'token_string   =', token_string );   // "mi_token"
console.log( '!token_string  =', !token_string );  // false
console.log( '!!token_string =', !!token_string ); // true
```

Quizás ahora se entienda el primer párrafo mejor con los ejemplos:

- *Convierte el valor a un valor que sea verdadero o falso*

---

> ¿Para que y porque se usa esta técnica en JavaScript?

Mayormente se usa la doble negación `!!` para forzar la conversión del tipo, es similar si queremos comparar con el operador [igualdad](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Comparison_Operators#Equality_operators) `==` también el tipo del valor, se tendría que usar el operador [estrictamente iguales](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Comparison_Operators#Identity_strict_equality_()) `===` .

Un ejemplo que se puede ver también en códigos reales:

```js
var token = 'mi_token';
console.log( token == true );   // false
console.log( !token == true );  // false
console.log( !!token == true ); // true
```

En el ejemplo estamos comparando el valor con `true` (booleano), si no usaríamos la doble negación `!!` nos devolvería siempre un falso.

Otros usos sería también para ofuscar el código, ejemplo:

```
// Ofuscado
val.enabled = !!userId;

// Parcialmente ofuscado/legible
val.enabled = (userId != 0) ? true : false;

// El más legible
val.enabled = (userId != 0);
```

También dicen que es más rápido si usamos la doble negación pero juzgan ustedes mismo, he creado un `Benchmark` en [jsPerf - Ver SpeedTest](https://jsperf.com/double-negation-javascript)...

Fuentes y donde se puede ver más ejemplos y explicaciones:

- [Doble negación exclamación en JavaScript](http://www.adrianrodriguez.org/2015/01/doble-negacion-exclamacion-en-javascript.html)
- [JavaScript - Double negative](https://codereviewvideos.com/blog/example-javascript-double-negative/)
- [What is the not not operator in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript)
- [Double Negation in JavaScript - What is the purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467475/double-negation-in-javascript-what-is-the-purpose)
- [JavaScript Double Negation Trick Trouble](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-double-negation-trick-trouble/)