# ¿Para qué sirve !!~ en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

¿Para qué sirve el operador `!!~`?

Lo estoy usando en este código que encontré en GitHub:

```
function multifiltros(array, filters) {
  const filterKeys = Object.keys(filters);

  return array.filter((item) => {

    return filterKeys.every(key => !!~filters[key].indexOf(item[key]));
//                                 ^^^
//                                 aquí
  });
}
```

Comment: Primera vez que lo veo, me hace pensar que no es vanillajs sino algún framework de javascript

Answer (score 17):

No es un solo operador, es el uso conjunto de tres operadores ( dos `!` y un `~`).

---

Antes de entrar en detalle sobre que hace en el código, una explicación sobre cada operador:

> `!` es la negación

La doble negación (`!!`) mayormente se usa para forzar la conversión del tipo a `boolean`, como por ejemplo:

```js
var token_null = null;
console.log( 'token_null   =', token_null );   // null
console.log( '!token_null  =', !token_null );   // true
console.log( '!!token_null =', !!token_null );  // false

console.log( '-----------' );

var token_undefined = undefined;
console.log( 'token_undefined   =', token_undefined );   // undefined
console.log( '!token_undefined  =', !token_undefined );  // true
console.log( '!!token_undefined =', !!token_undefined ); // false

console.log( '-----------' );

var token_0 = 0;
console.log( 'token_0   =', token_0 );   // 0
console.log( '!token_0  =', !token_0 );  // true
console.log( '!!token_0 =', !!token_0 ); // false
    
console.log( '-----------' );

var token_string = 'mi_token';
console.log( 'token_string   =', token_string );   // "mi_token"
console.log( '!token_string  =', !token_string );  // false
console.log( '!!token_string =', !!token_string ); // true
```

*Puedes ver mas información sobre la doble negación [aquí mismo en SO](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/125311)*

---

> `~` es NOT a nivel bit

Un ejemplo rápido:

```js
console.log(~0); // Es igual a -1

console.log(~-1); // Es igual a 0;

console.log(~11); // Es igual a -12;
```

Puedes leer mas sobre el NOT a nivel bits [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Bitwise_Operators#(Bitwise_NOT_o_Negaci%C3%B3n_a_nivel_de_bits))

---

### ¿Que hace ahí?

Ahora que terminamos la introducción, lo que hace `!!~filters[key].indexOf(item[key])` es devolver **false** solamente en el caso que **no** se encuentra la *key* dentro del array *filters*.

**¿Por que?**
Porque si no se encuentra el elemento, `.indexOf()` devuelve -1, al cual si le aplicamos `~` se convierte en 0, que equivale a `false`.

```js
var noEncontrado = -1;
console.log(!!~noEncontrado);
```

Ahora bien, si sacas el `!!` es totalmente el mismo comportamiento debido a como funciona el `.every()` , como puedes ver aquí:

```js
// -1 simula la situación en la que indexOf() no encuentre el elemento, el resto de los valores haría referencia a la posición del elemento

var prueba1 = [1,0,2,3,-1].every(a=>!!~a); // da false
console.log(prueba1);

var prueba2 = [1,0,2,3,-1].every(a=>~a); // da false
console.log(prueba2);

var prueba3 = [1,0,2,3,1].every(a=>!!~a); // da true
console.log(prueba3);

var prueba4 = [1,0,2,3,1].every(a=>~a); // da true
console.log(prueba4);
```

Comment: agregaria el !! es igual al === compara valor y tipo de dato, el segundo compara un bit realmente valido

Comment: Claro, tienes razón @JackNavaRow pero en este caso con el every, "no da problemas" al menos hasta donde pude comprobar.

Answer (score 1):

En concreto !!~ no es un operador, sino que es un conjunto de varios operadores. Lo estoy viendo y no le encuentro mucha utilidad, pero si te sirve de algo. Te dejo explicado por separado los dos operadores que pude identificar.

Con el `!!` haces una doble negación lo que transforma un valor en Booleano.

```
!true = false
!!true = true
```

Y el simbolo `~` es el NOT logico que lo que hace es invertir los bits

```
~5(decimal) => ~0101(binario) => 1010(binario) => 10(decimal)
```

Mas info: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp

Saludos!